# How to Unit test registerLocaleData in angular

Tags: angular, locale, karma-runner

I am trying to test the actual output from a date string conversion with angular 8, and Karma.

In my app.module I use the syntax: 
`registerLocaleData(localeNl, 'nl');`

In my template I use 
`{{date | date: 'MMMM yyyy'}}`

When I unit test the pipe conversion with :

```
element = fixture.nativeElement;
content = element.querySelector('.content');
expect(content.innerText).toContain('mei 2020')
```

I get the Karma error that the innerText is "May 2020" and not "mei 2020" but in the actual angular application it renders the text correctly "mei 2020". So How can I get the Karma environment to use the same locale as the application?

Comment: The same for currency pipe: the output {{amount | currency: "EUR" }} gives in the application  '€1.777,08' and in the Karma the output is '€1,777.08'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try providing it:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
...
registerLocaleData(localeNL, 'nl');
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nl' }], // you know the useValue here
});
```

As for the currency being `.` instead of `,`, I have no idea why that is happening.

Comment: and also the currency (€ 1.777,08) with space

Comment: Where do you get ```localeNL``` from?

Comment: I haven't done this but maybe `import localeNl from '@angular/common/locales/nl';`. https://gist.github.com/realappie/4e1f66e551f47549cd0306ad2e1fb0ef

Comment: get localeNL from import localeNl from '@angular/common/locales/nl';

Answer (score 0):

I just add another answer in case someone stumble upon this question, for Karma/Jasmine, you need to configure in test.ts file once and for all tests, you don't need to add `registerLocaleData` for each test, a simple code is below:

```
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR');
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
providers: [
  {
    provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR'
  }
 ]
});
```